# Include Data in Hook?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using the `set_update_hook()` function in the [karellen-sqlite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/karellen-sqlite/0.0.3) Python module to automatically send database changes to a function. Basically, it works like this:

```
from pysqlite2 import connect

def hook(conn, op, db_name, table_name, rowid):
    """Handle notification here. Do not modify the connection!"""

with connect(":memory:") as conn:
    conn.set_update_hook(hook)
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE a (int id);")
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO a VALUES (1);")
```

I am trying to determine if the info sent to `hook` contains the data that was inserted, updated, or deleted in the database.

So, after executing an `insert`, I printed the values of `hook`'s parameters:

```
conn = ['DataError', 'DatabaseError', 'Error', 'IntegrityError', 'InterfaceError', 'InternalError', 'NotSupportedError', 'OperationalError', 'ProgrammingError', 'Warning', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_update_hook', '_update_hook_cb', '_update_hook_last_error', 'close', 'commit', 'create_aggregate', 'create_collation', 'create_function', 'cursor', 'enable_load_extension', 'execute', 'executemany', 'executescript', 'in_transaction', 'interrupt', 'isolation_level', 'iterdump', 'last_update_hook_error', 'load_extension', 'rollback', 'row_factory', 'set_authorizer', 'set_progress_handler', 'set_trace_callback', 'set_update_hook', 'text_factory', 'total_changes'] 

op = UpdateHookOps.SQLITE_INSERT 

db_name = main 

table_name = test 

rowid = 3
```

But where is the data? Do I have to execute a separate query to retrieve it (in the case of an insert or update)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That mechanism is a wrapper around the [sqlite3_update_hook() C API function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html):

> The first argument to the callback is a copy of the third argument to `sqlite3_update_hook()`. The second callback argument is one of `SQLITE_INSERT`, `SQLITE_DELETE`, or `SQLITE_UPDATE`, depending on the operation that caused the callback to be invoked. The third and fourth arguments to the callback contain pointers to the database and table name containing the affected row. The final callback parameter is the rowid of the row. In the case of an update, this is the rowid after the update takes place.

So you get just enough information to identify the row.